# scrollIntoView not working on mobile in react useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, use-effect

I'm trying to implement my on carousel with the ability to drag on am image to get the next.
On desktop, everything works fine. On mobile, it does not. And its very interesting to me since if I run the same code in the console, it works.

[Here is a codesandbox with a recreation.](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-cookies-xszv8?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)

Comment: its working, long swipes sometimes don't seem to work but swipes inside the screen viewport are working.

Comment: Due to link rot, external links can go down over time, rendering the question useless. Please put a [mcve] in the question itself. You can use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. Is it scrolling an element into view, or dragging/using gestures to move your UI around? They are completely different things. Please provide a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example to the specific code with issue. In React you should also really be using a React ref to get to underlying DOMNodes versus querying the DOM directly.

Comment: The issue is `.scrollIntoView()` is not working @DrewReese

Comment: I've just retested your codesandbox, it seems it's working there. I then commented out the `elem.scrollIntoView` code (lines 17-21), and it ***did not*** scroll into view as I expected, then again uncommented those lines and it works again, as I would expect. So to me it still is unclear what the issue is you want resolved. Have you tested your code on a physical mobile device and not just a mobile view on a desktop browser?

Comment: Yes on desktop it works fine but both on mobile in dev tools and on a real mobile device, its not working for me, Its just not scrolling. Try here https://xszv8.csb.app/  I'm using Chrome @DrewReese

Comment: Well, in that last CSB link you specify the first image (`1529511792243__64720__db-207.jpg`) in your data array as the one to scroll into view, but it already is in view. If you specify the last image (`1529511873668__59353__db-207c.jpg`) it works scrolls the last image into view. Have you ensured you are running *the samecode* in all the places/devices you are testing on? FYI, a "mobile device" in the dev tools of your desktop browser is *still* your desktop browser, it's only a specifically sized viewport, not an accurate representation of how the code would run on a physical device.